# Clear Internet Explorer 6.0 browsing history using Script

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file

I was using the following script to delete the browsing history in IE 7.0

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255
```

But now I need a script to clear browsing history in IE 6.0

I get an error that "missing entry ClearMyTracksByProcess" I have passed different parameters like 2 ,5 etc and wasn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <shlguid.h> // Needed for CLSID_CUrlHistory
#include <urlhist.h> // Needed for IUrlHistoryStg2 and IID_IUrlHistoryStg2

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: code your application's behavior here.

        IUrlHistoryStg2* pHistory;  // We need this interface for clearing the history.
        HRESULT hr;
        DWORD cRef;
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        // Load the correct Class and request IUrlHistoryStg2
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUrlHistory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IUrlHistoryStg2, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pHistory));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
         // Clear the IE History
         hr = pHistory->ClearHistory();
        }
        // Release our reference to the 
        cRef = pHistory->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `INETCPL.CPL version 7.0` that ships with Internet Explorer 7 does have an entry-point named `ClearMyTracksByProcessW`, It's possible it is not present in IE6.

Hence may be a script is a more basic solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO * Cleaning Current User's Temp Folders *
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\*.*") DO DEL/S/Q/F "%%G\Cookies\*.*"
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\*.*") DO DEL/S/Q/F "%%G\Local Settings\Temp\*.*"
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\*.*") DO DEL/S/Q/F "%%G\Local Settings\History\*.*"
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\*.*") DO DEL/S/Q/F "%%G\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*.*"
Echo * Done *
PAUSE
CLS
```

(you can keep only the "delete" that interest you in this script)

However, as [reported in this thread](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-ie7-browsing-history-from-the-command-line/), it may not be enough.

---

The only other solution would be to use a (free) thirdparty utility:

[alt text http://www.ccleanerbeginnersguide.com/ccleanerhelp.png](http://www.ccleanerbeginnersguide.com/ccleanerhelp.png)[CCleaner](http://www.ccleanerbeginnersguide.com/scr/commandline.htm)

Other options are [mentionned in this thread](http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windowsxp/261874/Clear-IE-History-using-Batch-file-Recent):

- [index.dat](http://support.it-mate.co.uk/?mode=Products&p=Index.datSuite)
- [Xp Tweaks (See 24 right)](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)

Answer (score 0):

ClearMyTracks() was not part of IE6, so you cannot do the same trick.

If you just want to clear history, you can write a small program that just CoCreates(CLSID_CUrlHistory, IID_IUrlHistoryStg2) and then call [IUrlHistoryStg::ClearHistory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767715(VS.85).aspx).

Should be able to do it from VBScript as well, but I don't know the right mojo.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news folk's

Trying to delete internet history using ClearMyTracksByProcess on Win 7 with IE8/9 no longer works and you can only clean some of the files by running dos delete commands at startup because microsoft uses super hidden folders, locks files, well it a big mess and upsets Big Brother.

This code cleans IE8/9 plus FireFox and shared objects/flash cookies but if you want to delete Index.dat files then click my name to see the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Text;

namespace Fidling
{
    public static class SpywareRemoval
    {
        private static void RemoveSpywareFiles(string RootPath, string Path,bool Recursive)
        {
            string FullPath = RootPath + Path + "\\";
            if (Directory.Exists(FullPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo DInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FullPath);
                FileAttributes Attr = DInfo.Attributes;
                DInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                foreach (string FileName in Directory.GetFiles(FullPath))
                {
                    RemoveSpywareFile(FileName);
                }
                if (Recursive)
                {
                    foreach (string DirName in Directory.GetDirectories(FullPath))
                    {
                        RemoveSpywareFiles("", DirName, true);
                        try { Directory.Delete(DirName); }catch { }
                    }
                }
                DInfo.Attributes = Attr;
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveSpywareFile(string FileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                try { File.Delete(FileName); }catch { }//Locked by something and you can forget trying to delete index.dat files this way
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteFireFoxFiles(string FireFoxPath)
        {
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "cookies.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "content-prefs.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "downloads.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "formhistory.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "signons.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.json");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "permissions.sqlite");
        }

        public static void RunCleanup()
        {
            try { KillProcess("iexplore"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            try { KillProcess("FireFox"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            string RootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).ToLower().Replace("documents", "");
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects",false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\#local", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files", false);//Not working
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.History), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Wer", true);  
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches", false);          
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temp", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Apple Computer\QuickTime\downloads", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache", false);
            if (Directory.Exists(RootPath + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"))
            {
                string FireFoxPath = RootPath + @"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\";
                DeleteFireFoxFiles(FireFoxPath);
                foreach (string SubPath in Directory.GetDirectories(FireFoxPath))
                {
                    DeleteFireFoxFiles(SubPath + "\\");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void KillProcess(string ProcessName)
        {//We ned to kill Internet explorer and Firefox to stop them locking files
            ProcessName = ProcessName.ToLower();
            foreach (Process P in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (P.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith(ProcessName))
                    P.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hand on this..
this is what i use myself.

i summon a prompt box, edit it as you wish

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Clearing History 
echo Please close this window if opening this was a mistake.
pause
echo.
echo Clearing History: File Explorer
Del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*
Del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
Del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*
REG Delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU /VA /F
REG Delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths /VA /F 
echo.
echo Completed!
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Clearing History: Firefox
echo.
echo Scanning for 'Firefox' data
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
IF NOT EXIST "%DataDir%" GOTO NOFIREFOXDIR
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
GOTO YESFIREFOXDIR
:NOFIREFOXDIR
echo.
echo Firefox NOT found!
echo.
GOTO CHROMESETUP
:YESFIREFOXDIR
echo.
echo Completed!
echo.
:CHROMESETUP
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Clearing History: Google Chrome
echo.
echo Scanning for 'Google Chrome' data.
set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
IF NOT EXIST "%ChromeDir%" GOTO NOCHROMEDIR
del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"
GOTO YESCHROMEDIR
:NOCHROMEDIR
echo.
echo Google Chrome NOT found!
echo.
GOTO OPERASETUP
:YESCHROMEDIR
echo.
echo Completed!
echo.
:OPERASETUP
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Clearing History: Opera
echo.
echo Scanning for 'Opera' data.
set OperaDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera
set OperaDir2=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera
IF NOT EXIST "%OperaDir%" GOTO OPERA2
del /q /s /f "%Opera%"
rd /s /q "%Opera%"
:OPERA2
IF NOT EXIST "%OperaDir2%" GOTO NOOPERADIR
del /q /s /f "%Opera2%"
rd /s /q "%Opera2%"
GOTO YESOPERADIR
:NOOPERADIR
echo.
echo Opera NOT found!
echo.
GOTO APPLESETUP
:YESOPERADIR
echo.
echo Completed!
echo.
:APPLESETUP
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Clearing History: Apple Safari
echo.
echo Scanning for 'Apple Safari' data.
set AppleDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Applec~1\Safari
set AppleDir2=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Applec~1\Safari
IF NOT EXIST "%AppleDir%" GOTO APPLESETOP
del /q /s /f "%AppleDir%\History"
rd /s /q "%AppleDir%\History"
del /q /s /f "%AppleDir%\Cache.db"
del /q /s /f "%AppleDir%\WebpageIcons.db"
:APPLESETOP
IF NOT EXIST "%AppleDir2%" GOTO NOAPPLEDIR
del /q /s /f "%AppleDir2%"
rd /s /q "%AppleDir2%"
GOTO YESAPPLEDIR
:NOAPPLEDIR
echo.
echo Apple Safari NOT found!
echo.
GOTO INTESETUP
:YESAPPLEDIR
echo.
echo Completed!
echo.
:INTESETUP
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Clearing History: Microsoft Internet Explorer
echo.
echo Scanning for 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' data.
set IEDataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Intern~1
IF NOT EXIST "%IEDataDir%" GOTO HISTORYDIR
del /q /s /f "%IEDataDir%"
rd /s /q "%IEDataDir%"
:HISTORYDIR
set History=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
IF NOT EXIST "%History%" GOTO IETEMPDIR
del /q /s /f "%History%"
rd /s /q "%History%"
:IETEMPDIR
set IETemp=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1
IF NOT EXIST "%History%" GOTO COOKIESDIR
del /q /s /f "%IETemp%"
rd /s /q "%IETemp%"
:COOKIESDIR
set Cookies=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
IF NOT EXIST "%Cookies%" GOTO FLASHCCC
del /q /s /f "%Cookies%"
rd /s /q "%Cookies%"
:FLASHCCC
set FlashCookies=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flashp~1
IF NOT EXIST "%FlashCookies%" GOTO FINAL
del /q /s /f "%FlashCookies%"
rd /s /q "%FlashCookies%"
:FINAL
echo.
cls
echo.
echo Thank you for using our cleaner...
echo.
pause
```